# Overlay with position fixed does not show all content inside div

Tags: javascript, css

I created an overlay inside a div with position fixed because I want to show it using a slide effect starting from the very top of the website.

Here is the css code:

```
.overlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 z-index: 9999;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 1040px;//as example

}
```

The problem is that not all content inside the overlay div is shown. I tried also to insert an overflow: auto, but it does not work.

Here is the example:
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/mwaL1g4g/14/)

Comment: The overlay's content is too large and position fixed means exactly that: fixed and thus not scrollable if the viewport is too small.

Comment: You cannot use `position:fixed` as, once applied, the overlay has no relationship to the"parent" div. All positioning etc is now related to the viewport...and the viewport only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the fixed position, you can add a scrollbar to it with `overflow : auto;` property and a 100% height.

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
     z-index: 9999;
     color: white;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwaL1g4g/16/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.colTwo{
  height: 840px;
  background-color: green;
}

.show {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #333;
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  position:fixed;
}


.overlay {
  position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
     z-index: 9999;
     color: white;
     height: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 70%;
     margin: auto;
     overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use fixed?

```
Position : absolute
```

Does the trick for me if i understand correctly what you want.

Comment: Hi, yes I would like to use fixed as position. When I click on the related class the div should appear fixed because I need to call it from every part of the website coming from the fixed nav on the very top.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the `overflow` property on a `fixed` element because it's already out of the flow. Since the content are wrapped within `container`, one of the solutions is to make it scrollable.

```
.container{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```